# SpringBoot 2.4.0 - CrudRepository autowiring error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, autowired

Good morning,
I am working on a multi module Springboot project with maven. For the time being, there is only a sub module called "students-microservice" where I have declared an interface that extends CrudRepository and which I inject with autowired into my service.
The main class only contains the @SpringBootApplication annotation and when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Field studentRepository in com.eara.microservices.app.students.service.StudentServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.eara.microservices.app.students.repository.StudentRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @ org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired (required = true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.eara.microservices.app.students.repository.StudentRepository' in your configuration.
```

If I add the @Repository annotation to the interface extending CrudRepository and run it again, I get the same error.
If I add the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation with the package containing the repository to the main class, I get the error:

```
Description:

Field studentRepository in com.eara.microservices.app.students.service.StudentServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

The parent pom.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <modules>
        <module>students-microservice</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.eara.microservices.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-microservice</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>parent-microservice</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <testcontainers.version>1.15.0</testcontainers.version>
        <io.swagger.version>1.6.2</io.swagger.version>
        <model.mapper.version>2.3.7</model.mapper.version>
        <mariadb-java-client.version>2.5.4</mariadb-java-client.version>
        <mariadb.version>1.15.1</mariadb.version>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0-M5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jpa, crud repository -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>${io.swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${io.swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${io.swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Model Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>${model.mapper.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.22</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
                <version>${mariadb-java-client.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

The pom.xml of the submodule is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent-microservice</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.eara.microservices.app</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>students-microservice</artifactId>

    <properties>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>students-service</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Someone would be kind to help me to resolve this issue, please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Ernesto.

Comment: The error is most probably because your spring boot class (the main class) is not at the higher lever package of all the packages. By default Spring do Component Scan to its own package and sub packages. Just take your main class to the root package and it would work for you.

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I am using spring boot 2.5.4.. getting similar error.